# Prevent React JS from overriding scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, prototype

I'm not that experienced with JavaScript, however, I am familiar enough to navigate and write my own code.

I've been spending a lot of time trying to figure out an issue I'm getting with HTTP requests, only to recently realize that it's likely a specific script other that might causing this.

**It looks as though it may be React JS.**

I'm not familiar with this.
(I did look it up, and searched a lot for any no-conflict options)

**Basically, from the moment I execute "XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open" to monitor incoming HTTP requests, all of my scripts appear to be passing through a React JS file.**

I assume this, because I'm logging the steps and results of my script in the browser's console, and they are all being attributed to "commons-##########.js" from the moment I run that XMLHttpRequest.prototype.

I see this in the header of the commons-##########.js file:

```
/** @license React v16.4.1
 * react-dom.production.min.js
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013-present, Facebook, Inc.
```

The problem is that it appears to be affecting my own scripts from functioning properly.

Does anyone know why this might happen, and how it could be fixed?
I'd like my JS scripts to run without interference from React JS.

(It's not my own website, but a website I regularly use for business. The modifications are to assist me, nothing malicious.)

Thank you.

---

Please note that I'm aware that the commented portion I highlighted will not affect my code. I only put that to explain why I believe it's a React JS script that is causing the problem.

This is what the actual error looks like in the console (a portion of it):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:122:29)
    at XMLHttpRequest.a (commons-9702d5b….js:34)
(anonymous) @   VM14804:122
a   @   commons-9702d5b….js:34
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)     
XMLHttpRequest.send @   VM14804:70
(anonymous) @   commons-9702d5b….js:34
(anonymous) @   commons-9702d5b….js:34
```

I've tried many methods, and I don't see any issue with why I cannot JSON parse the response, or do many other things.
Something about that code is interfering with my own.

The JS script is a long, minified file, so it would be difficult to pin down a lone offending portion of code.

Comment: I've noticed this when I checked the console records (after the React script seems to take over): Any time I post something to Console afterwards, it's being attributed through the react JS. I see this line highlighted: "a && Function.prototype.apply.call(a, i, e)". So my thoughts is that some "prototype" function of React, is colliding with my own. Maybe simultaneous XMLHttpRequests. The issue definitely starts from the moment I call XMLHttpRequest.prototype.
It seems to extend outside of prototype after, even with basic config.log writes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99.99% sure the problem isn't with React. The `commons-#.js` file is the result of your scripts being bundled with any 3rd party libraries you're using (like React) into one file for efficient loading from a web server - it's standard practice, and very unlikely to cause any issues. The `/** @license React v16.4.1` comment you're seeing at the top of the file is simply because the bundling process has been configured to retain license information in the output.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
1) I'm very sure that the React script isn't coming from me/my scripts. It's source is the website/domain I'm running my scripts on (I run them through my own Chrome Extension), I don't own the site.
2) I understand that the /** @license React v16.4.1 is simply a comment, I was just pointing out how I realized the offending script apparently belongs to the React library.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Could you post your code where you're making the request and trying to parse the response? It'd also be helpful if you pasted the response body so we can see that and validate that the problem isn't with your stack, rather than the code in commons.js

Comment: Hi, these are the portions of my code that may be useful. It's a very basic function, just opening XMLHttpRequest, listen for all requests, and for now, post the responses to console.
Code: XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open .. this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {.. console.log(this.response) .. open.call(this, m, u, a, us, p); };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);

The response is actually very huge, however, I feel that it's being disfigured by the other JS.
"Blob(48999) {size: 48999, type: "application/json"}"
I can't do anything with it so far, even using Blob functions.

Comment: The reason I think that I may be receiving some deformed request, is that I can read the response very easily, using any other external method.
In Chrome Network view, it's easy to read. I also installed several Chrome Extensions that record/read HTTP requests, and the data is all very clear and easy to read, not a huge Blob file, which I can't access data from.

Comment: I'm seeing this when I check the console records (after the React script seems to take over), any time I post something to Console afterwards, it's being attributed through the react JS. I see this line highlighted: "a && Function.prototype.apply.call(a, i, e)" So my thoughts is that some "prototype" function of React, is colliding with my own. Maybe simultaneous XMLHttpRequests. The issue definitely starts from the moment I call XMLHttpRequest.prototype.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by JSON response that was received in wrong form from a server or was incorrectly transformed.

> Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

error means that `[object ...]` string (the result of coercion of an object to a string) was passed to `JSON.parse`. It's unknown where this error originates from. *XHR* requests can be checked in devtools *Network* tab to identify whether the problem was caused by wrong response, so it could be reported to API owner.

The problem isn't caused by React. React itself can't do anything like that, it's **UI** library. It doesn't use `XMLHttpRequest` in any way. The error is caused by some piece of code that uses both React and XHR. It likely can be debugged in this part of a stack:

```
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:122:29)
    at XMLHttpRequest.a (commons-9702d5b….js:34)
(anonymous) @   VM14804:122
```

The problem needs to be fixed by a party this code belongs to - website owner, another browser extension, third-party components you're using, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was just mentioning that I can read the response very clearly by all other methods. Only when it's being interacted through that other JS, is the format difficult to process. - 
"The reason I think that I may be receiving some deformed request, is that I can read the response very easily, using any other external method. In Chrome Network view, it's easy to read. I also installed several Chrome Extensions that record/read HTTP requests, and the data is all very clear and easy to read, not a huge Blob file, which I can't access data from."

Comment: Yes, you may be right, that I may need to figure this out by myself.
I'll look into it more later when I wake.

I did notice something interesting, I'll try adding it to the OP.

I'm seeing this when I check the console records (after the React script seems to take over), any time I post something to Console afterwards, it's being attributed through the react JS.

I see this line highlighted:
"a && Function.prototype.apply.call(a, i, e)"

So my thoughts is that some "prototype" function of React, is colliding with my own.
Maybe simultaneous XMLHttpRequests.

Comment: The reason why a stack contains references to React is that React-powered components trigger XHR request - or anything else these components do. The problem has nothing to do with React itself, as you originally assumed. `Function.prototype.apply.call(a, i, e)` isn't related to React 'prototypes' in any way. It's just an obscure way to call `a` function. It's unknown what the cause of 'colliding' could be in your case, this depends on your case. Possibly that the exception is propagated to global error handler, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror .